# ng-repat not working in array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I try to ng-repeat my data but it not working

```
<div ng-if="isDocPresent(doc, $index)">
      <div ng-repeat="x in arr[$index] track by $index">
        <div class="title" ng-if="$last">{{x || 'N/A'}}</div>
        {{x.title}} {{x.document_url}} {{document_url}}
        </div>
      </div>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.isDocPresent = function(doc, index) {
      if ($scope.parentCtrl.docsList && $scope.parentCtrl.docsList[appConstants.DOCUMENT_CATEGORY[doc]])
      {
        $scope.arr[index] = $scope.parentCtrl.docsList[appConstants.DOCUMENT_CATEGORY[doc]];
        return true;
      }
    };
```

it always print only this **`{{x || 'N/A'}}`**

Comment: What happens if you remove the `$` in your `html` as in `ng-repeat="x in arr[index] track by $index"`?

Comment: If you inspect the element tied to your controller in your console and type `angular.element($0).scope().arr` what is the output?

Comment: Page shows `{{x || 'N/A'}}` that means your page has some error, check console..

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the $index variable, which is defined in the ng-repeat, ie not in the containing block around it. Try this instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in arr track by $index">
  <div ng-if="isDocPresent(doc, $index)">
    <div class="title" ng-if="$last">{{x || 'N/A'}}</div>
      {{x.title}} {{x.document_url}} {{document_url}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```